# How disable triggering onClick after onTouch

Tags: android, onclick, ontouchlistener, android-popupwindow, ontouch

How disable instant triggering onClik button afrer onTouch `MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE`. I have a popupwindow, when I click on the outside and on the background I have a button, edittext or checkbox, then the button is triggered, if this is edittext, then the focus moves to it, if checkbox then it becomes checked. How disable click after onTouch?
added video example https://youtu.be/yyT47y-CL-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new StateListDrawable())
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```